# How may I add background color to dynamically added child rows in Datatables?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am adding child rows dynamically to datatables to show data fetched dynamically. Here is the code for that:

```
var oTable = $('#myTable5').DataTable();
var tr = $('#'+id).closest('tr');
var row = oTable.row( tr );
console.log(row);
if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
}
else {
    // Open this row
    row.child( format(dataSet) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
}
```

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to add a background color to this child row!! I have tried a lot of things and nothing has worked. If you have successfully achieved this, please help. 
Posting on datatable forums yielded no working response.

TIA.

Comment: add this in CSS tr{background-color: #f2f2f2;}

Comment: This will add background color to ALL rows! The question is specifically about child rows added dynamically to datatables.

Comment: to new row or all `shown` rows ?

Comment: To the new row only

Comment: I suggest you to add a class in child row and then create a css for that class with !important

Comment: So I tried doing that but it did not work. Tried using row.addClass("xyz") but got an error that addClass is not a function

Comment: Where is your html code for the child row?

Comment: The HTML contents are fetched via AJAX.

Comment: i saw your fiddle but please note that you are changing the background of the parent row and NOT the child row. Cheers.

Comment: @AmanKejriwal are you able to add your class to the child row at the point where you define it in HTML?

Comment: Mark thats where i am stumped. My child html is a table that I create and deliver via Ajax. I can change the css of that table. BUT, the issue is that the child tr created by the javascript code I shared should have the background color - but i cannot find a way to access its background color property.

Comment: @AmanKejriwal are you saying that when you add a class to the `tr` of your table (the one being delivered by Ajax) it is not being applied in the browser? The code you provided above is not really relevant. This would be a lot easier if we could see the code that the child row is using for its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set background for child row as below. `rowBackground` is a css class.
Working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/61gxkv4w/)

```
row.child("child row",'rowBackground').show();
```

Comment: Works! How did you figure this out?

Comment: Good that it resolved your problem :). I went through DataTable forum and found one solution. Luckily I still have that url in my history ;)  here it is https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26601/add-css-to-child-row

Comment: Really appreciated mate!

Comment: More power to you :)

Comment: This helped me. I didn't notice that there was a class you could pass in when doing row.child() to create the child. This is what I needed! Now I can customize child rows with CSS.